# What will be the size of this structure ? Online Compiler showing different

Tags: c++, c, struct, structure

What will be the output of this ?

```
struct abc{
char i[5];
char b[8];
int j ;
};
```

`struct abc s1;`

According to me it should be 1 * 5 + 1 * 8 + 4 bytes  = 17 bytes

When I do `sizeof(s1)` it shows 20 ! Why?

Comment: Possibly because there is padding between members to have them properly aligned. `<[iiiii][bbbbbbbb]###[jjjj]>`

Comment: The size and alignment requirement for `int` depends on the platform. `sizeof(int)` isn't necessarily 4.

Comment: Try putting the int first. In general, always list the largest members in a union first, then next biggest etc.

Comment: @ArthurKalliokoski: possibly (with members ordered by size) the padding goes to the end of the struct rather than the middle :-)

Comment: @ArthurKalliokoski that seems like an arbitrary choice to me. What advantage would following that rule have?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks , I believe its due to padding of different compilers

Comment: @pmg how did you decide that only ### 3 padds will be added ?

Comment: Because you said `sizeof (struct abc)` is `20`

Comment: oh okay . I thought you computed something @pmg

Comment: @pmg can we connect on linkedIn ?

Comment: To the people replying to my comment about putting ints first, you want ints to be aligned to the word size of your machine so the bus doesn't have to make two or more accesses, but chars are accessed byte by byte so alignment doesn't matter for them. Somewhat similar for short ints.

Comment: Maybe you would ask "why put padding between `b` and `j`?" ... Well because `b` has underlying `char` type and doesn't require alignment, and `j` requires alignment on address multiple of `4`.

Comment: nope @Anirudh_k, I have no account on linkedin.

Comment: @pmg makes sense !! Great

Comment: @pmg any social media account ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is my best social media available :-)

Comment: @couka that'll minimize the padding because larger members have alignment requirement not smaller than smaller members, so internal paddings won't be necessary. See [The Lost Art of Structure Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/)